# Error: snap: command not found

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, snap

I upgraded from 14.04.x to 16.04 (64 bit) over the weekend. OMGubuntu! just had a post about how notes could be installed as a snap.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then

```
sudo snap install notes
```

then enter my password..

```
sudo: snap: command not found
```

What is up? What am I missing? I don't want to miss out on this new snap fun.

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo updatedb && locate '*bin*/snap'`?

Comment: None, there is no output.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The following worked on my system:

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
sudo snap install notes
```

I needed to log out and then back in for Dash to find 'Notes':

[image]

**Note:** There is currently some confusion with *another* Xenial package called [snap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/snap) which gives: 'location of genes from DNA sequence with hidden markov model'. If you get `dpkg` errors to do with this package when installing `snapd` (in particular overwriting of commonly named man pages) run the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge snap
```

And then you should be right to go :)

The application 'Notes' was perhaps a little underwhelming, other packages look a little more promising:

```
andrew@athens:~$ snap find
Name                   Version                  Summary
audovia                3.2.2                    Database application for making music using JFugue MusicStrings
beagleblack            3.1                      OEM Beagle Bone Black
canonical-dragon       0.7.1                    The gadget snap for the dragonboard
canonical-i386         3.1.i386                 The gadget snap for generic i386 systems
canonical-pc           3.2                      AMD64 generic package
canonical-pc-linux     4.4.0-18+20160419.13-26  The ubuntu-core kernel snap
canonical-pi2          3.2                      Raspberry Pi 2 support package
go-example-webserver   16.04-4                  Minimal Golang webserver for snappy
hello-world            6.0                      Hello world example
http                   4.6692016                HTTPie in a snap
john-the-ripper        1.8.0-11765-g9a09113     John the Ripper Jumbo password cracker for Linux
links                  2.12-1                   Web browser running in text mode
moon-buggy             1.0.51.9                 Drive a car across the moon
morse-converter-py     1-2                      Simple command-line Morse converter
nmap                   7.12SVN-0.4              Nmap ("Network Mapper") is a free and open source utility for network discovery and security auditing
notes                  0.0.8~snap3.gita80fd1c   Note-taking application, write down your thoughts
shout                  0.53.0                   A self hosted web IRC client
sshtron                1.0                      multiplayer Tron via ssh
tmux                   2.3bump1                 tmux
tor-middle-relay       0.2.7.6-6                Essential infrastructure node for Tor network
ubuntu-calculator-app  2.1+snap3                Ubuntu Calculator application for the Unity 7 desktop
ubuntu-clock-app       3.6+snap3                Ubuntu Clock application for the Unity 7 desktop
ubuntu-core            16.04+20160419.20-55     The ubuntu-core OS snap
xkcd-webserver         16.04-5                  Show random XKCD compic via a build-in webserver
yacas                  1.4.2                    Yet Another Computer Algebra System
```

Interesting times ahead...

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.0.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/snap.1.gz', which is also in package snap 2013-11-29-1ubuntu2
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.0.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: That is a clash with some DNA software: http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/snap named 'snap' believe it or not. Looks like the man pages are named the same.  Try `sudo apt-get remove snap && sudo apt-get install snapd` and you should be ok...

Comment: Awesome it worked! Thank you. Should I accept your answer as is with our comments, or should your comment information be added to the answer before i accept it?

Comment: I have added in some words about the package problems of `snap` and `snapd`. Probably should be also added as a bug report in Launchpad....

Answer (score 6):

There are 4 steps:

1. `sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install snapd`

Then, install whatever you need, for example:

4. `sudo snap install rocketchat-desktop` or `sudo snap install notes`

Comment: Thanks. That worked when apt showed snap already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Installing snappy:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-snappy-cli
```

Installing snaps:

```
sudo snap install <package>
```

Comment: I did try that but it caused dependency errors

Comment: What dependency errors do you get?

Comment: `ubuntu-snappy-cli` is a dummy transitional package.